# Overriding High DPI Scaling from the Command Line

Tags: windows-10, scaling, high-dpi

I am compiling and building an OpenCV app on Windows 10, which shows some images.
I want to overrride the high DPI scaling behavior and set it to "Application".

I can do this fine on the `.exe` file by: Right-Click->Properties->Compatibility Tab and checking the checkbox.:

[image]

Is there a command line tool I can use to do that as part of a script?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**You make a bat file script.**

Here's how.

Make sure where the application is placed.

If the application is 64 bit `"%programfiles%\<appfoldername>\<app>.exe"`

If the application is 32 bit `"%programfiles(x86)%\<appfoldername>\<app>.exe"`

**`~HIGHDPIAWARE`** Indicates value of Override high DPI scaling behavior  **(Application)**

**`~DPIUNAWARE`** Indicates value of Override high DPI scaling behavior  **(System)**

**`"~GDIDPISCALING DPIUNAWARE"`** Indicates value of Override high DPI scaling behavior  **(System Enhanced)** add double quote also

I am doing this for Itunes (64 bit).

***Particular User***

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /V "%programfiles%\iTunes\iTunes.exe" /T REG_SZ /D ~HIGHDPIAWARE /F
```

***All User***

```
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /V "%programfiles%\iTunes\iTunes.exe" /T REG_SZ /D ~HIGHDPIAWARE /F
```

Comment: So the Win10 prop-dlg actually generates a registry entry too?

Comment: yes. i have tested in windows 10 it worked. its registry to be changed

Comment: Thanks! Will check. Based on your answer I found [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/11/21/disabling-dpi-scaling-on-windows-8-1-the-enterprise-way/) from MS which essentially says the same thing :-).

Comment: On Windows 10, I needed a space between the tilde and the dpi scaling value -- `"~ DPIUNAWARE"`

Comment: From  @AdiShavit MS link and my own experimentation, "Note that there is a space between the tilde and the HIGHDPIAWARE."

Comment: Be sure to change both HKCU and HKLM. Also use quotes around any of these options (e.g. `"~ DPIUNAWARE"`). Finally, be sure to have the space in there between `~` and `DPIUNAWARE`, or whichever mode you're going for.

Answer (score 1):

Following the previous advice I added the reg value `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` with a value of `~ DPIUNAWARE` including the space after the tilde.

However, it turned out that this DOES NOT work, UNLESS I set and remove the corresponding setting for the current user in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`.

So my solution follows those above but requires the HKCU key to be set and reset in advance.